# At what chapter of the manga does the first season of DanMachi conclude?

Tags: danmachi

*DanMachi*, originally a LN has been adapted into a manga and an anime. The anime (S1) ends with Hermes declaring Bell to be Zeus' grandson.

I wanted to pick up the manga. What chapter continues the story?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the **light novel**: The first season of *DanMachi* represents volume 1 to 5 of the light novel. If you want to continue where the anime left off, start with **volume 6**.

For the **manga**: The anime ended in **volume 8 ch. 34**.

In my opinion, reading volume 1 to 5 of the light novel still has value, since not everything in the light novel is covered in the anime. Some parts of the story go deeper in the light novels. As compared with *Sword Art Online* light novel which is exactly like the anime.